# Rails group model that can own groups that can own users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to model groups and users for my app, and I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to do it.

I have users, and I have admins. I don't have a model for groups yet. I'd like a group to be able to own multiple users, and users could have multiple groups. To complicate things further, groups could have multiple users through other groups.

```
class Group
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :users
  has_many :users, through: :groups
end


class User
  belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Admin
  has_many :groups
end
```

I think I need a membership table. Then each user would be connected to a group through a membership. But then how could I connect groups --> groups --> users?

```
class Membership
  ?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple pointers here.

`belongs_to_many` is not a thing, at least as of the latest version I'm familiar with. Maybe you mean `has_and_belongs_to_many` or probably `has_many :groups, through: :memberships`. I'm going to use this latter form below.

In order to use the `through :groups` option in the `Group` class, you first need to define a `:groups` association. If all you are trying to define it as is any other `Group` that has a `User` that is a member of both that and this `Group`, then you can do this easily:

```
class Membership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :users
end
```

You might want to rename this association to be a little less confusing:

```
has_many :connected_groups, through: :users, source: :groups
```

Now you want to define *another* `users` association on `Group` that represents the users of any connected group. You need a different name, you cannot meaningfully define two associations of the same name (how would you access one vs. the other?). So I'd suggest using the names `connected_groups` and `connected_users`, or something similar:

```
class Group
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :connected_groups, through: :users, source: :groups
  has_many :connected_users, through: connected_groups, source: :users
end
```